# Android: Compress a bitmap with few ram abuse

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, jpeg

when I call

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
```

I have an out of memory error because the file is too big.
How can I compress this file without abusing of the ram and without scaling it?
Please, help me =(

this is what i could do for now (i found this code here on stack)

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
    File compressedFilePicture;
    try {
        compressedFilePicture = createImageFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(compressedFilePicture);
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESS_VALUE, fOut);
        new File(filepath).delete();
        filepath = compressedFilePicture.getAbsolutePath();
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
        sc.string = filepath;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need to load the bitmap on ram a slice a time.. any idea??

Answer (score 0):

```
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
    File compressedFilePicture;
    try {
        compressedFilePicture = createImageFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(compressedFilePicture);
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESS_VALUE, fOut);
        new File(filepath).delete();
        filepath = compressedFilePicture.getAbsolutePath();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inSampleSize = 4;  //u can use 2/4/8/16....ect
Uri uri = getImageUri(filepath);     
InputStream in = in = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
        sc.string = filepath;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```